# Session Flash Data is changing "magically", why?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables, codeigniter-2

I have a project built on top of CI 2.1.3 and PHP 5.3.3. As per docs [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html) » Flash Data section when I set a flashdata session var it should be available only for the next request, right?

I have made the following test:

```php
class auth1 extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('string');
        $key   = random_string('alnum', 8);
        $value = random_string('alnum', 20);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('csrfkey', $key);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('csrfvalue', $value);

        echo '<pre>';

        var_dump($this->session->flashdata('csrfkey'));
        var_dump($this->session->flashdata('csrfvalue'));
    }

    public function index2()
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($this->session->flashdata('csrfkey'));
        var_dump($this->session->flashdata('csrfvalue'));
    }
}
```

I would expect to have the same values when I call `/auth/index2`, right? Surprise somehow those are changing, see below:

```
// /auth/index
string(8) "meo6dhEr"
string(20) "JNNN07XMXfmADzYw6cKc"

// /auth/index2
string(8) "I2vmFRuO"
string(20) "CbDhiD8CkY3plOK7Hg7B"
```

Any ideas? I am not setting them in `index2` just trying to get them however they are changing, why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are experiencing. I've downloaded the *same* code and tried it on my localhost. The only time index2's values change is when I visit index, not when I directly visit index2 - and that makes sense as index is setting the values; and since it is also getting rendered there, it refreshes it when you reload index.

Comment: Are you positive this is the only code working with those? You should either have the same values or it not existing. Is index() getting called at all when you go to index2 because it's just overriding the previous values then.

Comment: ^ exactly what i think is happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would expect to have the same values when I call `/auth/index2`, right?

Nope. And you've actually already explained why:

> when I set a flashdata session var it should be **available only for the next request**, right?

Those `var_dump()`s that you do in `index()` don't show the `$key`, `$value` contents that you just set. They show the values that you've set in a *previous* `index()` call that wasn't followed by a call to `index2()`.

Confusing, I know. CI2 is like that ... riddled with bugs and weird stuff, which is why *it was discontinued yeas ago*. Upgrade to the latest CI 3.x as soon as possible.

Also, CodeIgniter has it's own CSRF protection mechanism - you don't need to implement it. And `random_string()` is not really random ... don't use it for security.

Comment: I wish I could upgrade to CI 3.x but is not possible this are really old legacy systems in prod currently and we've to fix any issue. Anyway we're moving to C# so no more CI